# PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\AndroidSDK]!

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk, react-native

Проблема с эмулятором андроид студии. В результате поиска информации на просторах интернета нашел решение в создании локальных переменных, сделал все как надо, но выдало такую ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
P.S. Это все делается для того, чтобы настроить удаленную отладку для react-native. Если есть какие-то варианты помимо этого, то будьте добры подсказать

Answer (score -1):

Вообщем, вся проблема в том, что необходимо, чтоб в путь переменной ANDROID_HOME проходил через корневую папку и важно, чтоб название корневой папки было на латинице

Comment: А у автора вопроса с этим какие-то несоответствия? У него на латинице и корневая папка